# Magento 2.1 move currency symbol for rich snippets

Tags: magento-2.1, rich-snippets

All M2 themes I have tested do not have proper structured data/rich snippets.  The currency symbol is in the price span, and gets a warning:

An example: [link to snippet](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url#url=http%3A%2F%2Fmagento2-demo.nexcess.net%2Fhero-hoodie.html)
Problem code cleaned up a bit:

```
<span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span  data-price-amount="54"  data-price-type="finalPrice" itemprop="price">
    <span class="price">$54.00</span>    </span>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
</span>
```

Error: `price   $54.00 (The property $54.00 is not a valid price specification. Find out more about http://schema.org/price.)`

If the $ is taken out of `<span class="price">$54.00</span>` like this it validates fine:

```
<span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
$<span  data-price-amount="54"  data-price-type="finalPrice" itemprop="price">
<span class="price">54.00</span>    </span>
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
```

But I cannot find which files are creating the price code and which code to change.  What is the best way to validate the structured data?

Answer (score 3):

This is proper solution and worked

Go to extended file of this:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

Replace:

> $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="price"' :

With:

> $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="price" content="' . $block->getDisplayValue() . '"':

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7173

Answer (score 0):

I edited this file -

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml
```

moved to theme

```
app\design\frontend\(Vendor)\(Store)\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml
```

The line

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

contains `$block->formatCurrency` which is causing the error.  Remove this or change it to `<?php echo $block->getDisplayValue(); ?>` and the price will now validate.

You can then hardcore the currency symbol before `<span <?php if ($block->getPriceId())` But there is a JavaScript code that will overide this file and add it in.  If you do not want this happening -

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\form.phtml
```

moved to

```
app\design\frontend\(Vendor)\(Store)\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\form.phtml
```

and remove the line - `priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});`  that was calling the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**After struggling for a long time with this problem I found this fix -**

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '',strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()))); ?>">
```

**Just insert that line above this one -**

```
<span class="price"><?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price,true,false) ?></span>
```

**All credit goes to -**

https://feedarmy.com/kb/magento-microdata-for-google-shopping/